# Setting gl_PointSize in my vertex shader prevents uv from being passed

Tags: three.js, shader

UPDATE: I made a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qifija/8/) to illustrate the issue. Why is the rectangle on the right not the same colors as the rectangle on the left? Wow. I just realized that it varies across browsers: On Windows, in Chrome 50.0.2661.102 and Firefox 46.0.1 left rectangle is correct, right rectangle is incorrect, and in Edge 20.10240.16384.0 they are both correct. Note that on Linux both Chrome (version 49.0.2623.108) and Firefox (version 46.0) are correct. How's that for variation?

I have the following vertex shader:

```
varying vec2 vUV;
varying vec3 vPosition;
varying vec3 vLightFront;
uniform float isCloud;

void main() {
  vUV = uv;

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
  if (isCloud == 1.0) {
    // gl_PointSize = 1.0;
  }
}
```

As soon as I comment in the line concering gl_PointSize vUV is not passed correctly to the fragment shader anymore, even when isCloud == 0.0. I assume this because the textures disappear on the rendered screen and I verified they are still available for texture lookups by trying to use gl_FragCoord as the index instead of vUV. Why is vUV not passed anymore when gl_PointSize is even mentioned? I wanted to share the same shader for a normal geometry and a point cloud in three.js, with just an if clause in the shader, but it turns out as soon as gl_PointSize is mentioned uv doesn't work for normal geometry.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that what you want/expect is valid. "Uv" in this case is a name for a buffer. Three js happens to label it this way and give it meaning for texture mapping.  You probably don't have any values inside of that buffer even though three.shadermaterial declared it for you. I'm not sure which value you would actually want there since you only have one point. Is it .5,.5, or 1,1, or 0,0?

Comment: I do have values in the uv buffer. I ended up having to split the vertex shader into two vertex shaders, one that sets gl_PointSize for the particles and one that doesn't for the regular geometry. It works now, but I am still curious why any mention of gl_PointSize in the shader kills the uv buffer, even for the branch that is not taken. I'll update the code to show what I mean about the if branch.

Comment: like i said, if you have [... Xa,Ya,Za ... ] in your buffer, and you set the gl_PointSize, the point is created at (Xa,Ya,Za). It gets rasterized from there and filled with pixels from wherever (Xa,Ya,Za) projected on screen. 

Let's say you have a corresponding [ ... Ua, Va ... ] at the same index, what do you expect to happen? What do Ua, and Va mean to a rasterized PointSprite originating from Xa,Ya,Za?

Comment: I'm not sure if this works, but a way to test if you have any values somewhere is to do something like `gl_FragColor = vec4( abs( vUV ) * 10000.0 , 0. , 1.);` If you get yellow, the attribute and the varying worked. I am assuming the entire quad will get filled with whatever the uv attribute is at that position index. if you have P1(12,5,7) and UV1(1,0) youll get a red quad at 12,5,7.

Comment: I made a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qifija/6/) to illustrate the issue. Why is the rectangle on the right not the same colors as the rectangle on the left? Wow. I just realized that it varies across browsers: In Chrome left rectangle is correct, right rectangle is incorrect, in Firefox both are incorrect, and in Edge they are both correct. How's that for variation?

Comment: perhaps starting with a leaner shader might help? :) Im going through it but there's lots of simulation stuff, something illustrating the behavior of just gl_PointSize?

Comment: @pailhead I've trimmed it down to the bare minimum: http://jsbin.com/qifija/7/ . Now there is flickering random behaviour in Firefox, though Edge and Chrome stay the same.

Comment: check answer, you are probably trying to access an uninitialized variable, hence the weird results, 0 on some platforms, garbage on others...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An acceptable workaround is to split the vertex shader into two vertex shaders, one for the point cloud and one for the regular geometry and avoid the conditionals. However, I filed a [Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=612418) and a [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1273464) so we will see whether it is important enough to fix, or whether the WebGL ES specification says undefined behaviour or similar (I couldn't find anything).

UPDATE: I've filed a [bug with ANGLE](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/angleproject/issues/detail?id=1380) and a [PR with Khronos for a new WebGL conformance test](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/pull/1686). You can run the test [here](https://emh.lart.no/WebGL/sdk/tests/conformance/rendering/point-size-varyings.html).

RESOLVED: The test PR was merged into Khronos WebGL and ANGLE seems to have confirmed the bug and resolve to fix it, unless they change the WebGL spec to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The flickering and random behavior is because of this i think:

```
if (isCloud == 1.0) {
  gl_PointSize = 15.0;
} else {
  vUV = uv;
}
```

You are not assigning anything to the varying `vUV` and the results are different on different platforms. On windows (ANGLE?) it will actually be filled with zeros i believe, while i'm seeing garbage in chrome on osx.

The solution for this is to send some values to the fragment shader

```
if (isCloud == 1.0) {
  gl_PointSize = 15.0;
  vUV = uv; //the same way you send a position attribute, you send the uv to a point cloud 
} else {
  vUV = uv;
}
```

Outputing this:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(vUV,0., a);
```

yields your circle, and a corresponding UV value. The point that is at `-1,0,-1` in the `position` attribute, has a corresponding value `0,0` in the `uv` attribute.

In your shader and code this results with a grid of circles, the bottom left is black, the top right is yellow.

You're not seeing this because you're not passing the uv attribute to the fragment shader.

Again, don't expect that you can use this to map a texture onto the rasterized point. You can color each point entirely from a single UV sample through using your `varying vec2 vUV`. For clipping this circle, and mapping a texture across the rasterized point, you should use `gl_PointCoord.xy`. Which you already are, so i'm not sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but it doesn't enlighten me. I am simply trying to combine two working shaders into one. The browser handles the cloud case correctly but makes incorrect assumptions for the not-cloud case (except Microsoft Edge, which is correct). In the point cloud case (isCloud == 1.0), I am neither assigning nor using vUV. In the other case (isCloud == 0.0), I am both assigning and using vUV. What I want to know is how can I make the right quad look like the left one without deleting gl_PointSize or gl_PointCoord from its shaders. If not possible I believe it's a browser bug.

Comment: Yeah i didn't understand the problem. This seems like a bug.

Comment: It seems like this is actually the problem `vec2 pos = (gl_PointCoord.xy - 0.5) * 2.0;` if i change gl_PointCoord.xy to just vec2(1.) this works, commenting and uncommenting the gl_PointSize doesn't break anything?

Comment: Yes that's true, commenting out either gl_PointCoord or gl_PointSize works, because ANGLE is checking for those in the shader and compiles a HLSL shader for D3D based on their occurence. Still a bug in ANGLE though.

Comment: is it checking for both though? i'm not very clear on this usage, i saw the discussion on the bug page. Are you 100% sure that this usage is valid though? I'm not sure whats supposed to happen when you set `GL.POINTS` but render with `gl_PointSize`.

Comment: At least make isCloud an int :)

Comment: Why are you trying to combine the shaders in the first place? You save a bit of overhead with drawcalls, but you have a conditional in both shaders.

Comment: It's checking for both and doing various things based on each. Conditionals based on uniforms are supposed to be fast. It seems common practice to make megashaders, [see here](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/175672-shader-conditionals) for perf implications.